# Access content of one iframe from within another iframe

Tags: jquery, iframe

I have this struct:

```
<body>
 <iframe name="here">
 <iframe name="other">
</body>
```

the body of iframe "other" is:

```
<div id="content">foo</div>
```

How can I access the content of "other" from within "here"?

I tried this to change the content:

```
$('#other',top.document).contents().find("#content").html("bar");
```

But this doesn't work

---

finally I managed to solve this without jquery:

```
top.frames['other].document.getElementById("content").innerHTML="bar"
```

But it would still be interesting how to solve this with jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two mistakes:

- the iframes identifyer here is name not id
- to access an instance in the top document use `window.top.document`

so the correct way to access `other` from within `here` it is:

```
$('[name="other"]',window.top.document).contents().find("#content").html("foo");
```

Answer (score 0):

'#' is used for ids in jQuery, for names you need to use `$('[name="ElementNameHere"]').doStuff();`